# Migrate Quote with Quote Number from one Salesforce Org to another

Tags: data-loader, quote, migration, data-migration, auto-number

I'm migrating Quote record of one salesforce instance to another Salesforce instance.
The Quote number in source org is in **Q-{MM}{YY}-{0000}** format.

I have changed the quote format in my target environment.

Can I move the quotes record with same Quote number to the target environment, given that Quote Number is standard field and I can't change it to text first?

If not what other options I have to maintain the Quote Number from the Target?

Comment: is your target org empty (no quotes)?

Comment: Yes, it's empty

Comment: What field is storing that quote number format as you said you changed the quote format in your target environment - what change did you actually do? The standard field (`Quote Number`) is an autonumber and, as far as I know, not customizable to fit your format - just always `{00000000}`. `Quote Name` is a text field and you could set whatever in it.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves We can change the format of standard Quote Number field

Answer (score 0):

Your objective is not possible

Because `QuoteNumber` is autonumber standard field, any insert into `Quote` will get the next available number

The best you can do is to:

- create a new Field on Quote called `LegacyQuoteNumber__c` or something like this (make it an external id)  and
- map using data loader or whatever migration tool you are using the source's QuoteNumber field to the target's LegacyQuoteNumber__c field
- add to the Quote layout

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Firstly in the target org change the quote number format to text and do your import.  The source org quote numbers will be preserved.  Now convert it back to autonumber and provide a a new start number, one after the maximum of your source org.  That it. Job done.  This works because behind the scenes the quote number is just a text field.